DNS servers not removed after VPN disconnection - 24.04.1 LTS
I'm using GlobalProtect VPN 6.2.0.1 client installed from .deb packet on my ubuntu (desktop) and all was working fine since I upgraded my Ubuntu to 24.04.1 LTS.  It does not require any configuration after installation and I use it via GUI (just entering gateway hostname and my credentials).
Now I spotted that when I'm connecting to the VPN, new DNS servers are twice added to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf.
At the end of /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf I have the following (1.1.1.x IPs are DNS servers from the VPN):
nameserver 1.1.1.1

nameserver 1.1.1.2

nameserver 192.168.100.1

Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.

nameserver 192.168.68.1

nameserver 1.1.1.1

nameserver 1.1.1.2

search dommain.com

When I disconnect from the VPN only two dns servers are removed, and /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf looks like this:
nameserver 1.1.1.1

nameserver 1.1.1.2

nameserver 192.168.100.1

Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.

nameserver 192.168.68.1

search dommain.com

So it looks like the same servers are added twice to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, and after VPN disconnection, 2 DNS and search domain are not removed.
When I restart systemd-resolved service after VPN disconnection with sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved, I can see the duplicated DNS servers disappear, and /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf looks as expected:
nameserver 192.168.100.1

nameserver 192.168.68.1

search .

I also spotted that I see two additional interfaces when I'm connected to the VPN: Global and gpd0:
me@ubuntu:~$ resolvectl

Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

  resolv.conf mode: foreign

Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1

       DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2

        DNS Domain: dommain.com


Link 3 (wwan0)

    Current Scopes: none

         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS
 DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (wlp0s20f3)

 Current Scopes: DNS

 Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS

 DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Current DNS Server: 192.168.68.1

       DNS Servers: 192.168.100.1 192.168.68.1


Link 5 (gpd0)

    Current Scopes: DNS

         Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS 

DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1

       DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2

        DNS Domain: ~.dommain.com

When I disconnect from the VPN, only gpd0 is removed. Global is still there with DNS servers from the VPN.
After restarting systemd-resolved service, it removes these DNS servers and resolv.conf mode is changed to stub.
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub 

Can someone advise what can cause this strange behavior and how to solve this issue permanently?
Here is ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
output before VPN connection:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 wrz 25 16:00 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

And output from cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
# This file is part of systemd.

#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file (or a copy of it placed in
# /etc/ if the original file is shipped in /usr/), or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/ directory. The latter is generally
# recommended. Defaults can be restored by simply deleting the main
# configuration file and all drop-ins located in /etc/.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf' to display the full config.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
DNSStubListenerExtra=127.0.0.1:53
ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
#StaleRetentionSec=0

And after the VPN is connected:
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62 wrz 25 16:25 /etc/resolv.conf -> /opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/network/config/resolv.conf

cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file (or a copy of it placed in
# /etc/ if the original file is shipped in /usr/), or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/ directory. The latter is generally
# recommended. Defaults can be restored by simply deleting the main
# configuration file and all drop-ins located in /etc/.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf' to display the full config.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
DNSStubListenerExtra=127.0.0.1:53
ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
#StaleRetentionSec=0

Also:
cat /opt/paloaltonetworks/globalprotect/network/config/resolv.conf

search dommain.com
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.1.1.2

After the VPN disconenction:
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 wrz 25 16:27 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search dommain.com

search dommain.com <---this should not be here after the VPN is disconnected

Is this a Server or Desktop installation? How did you install and configure GlobalProtect VPN? How do you connect and disconnect to the VPN? Please update and edit your original question with answers to these questions. Do not add in comments.

Before and after connecting to your VPN, what is the output of ls -l /etc/resolv.conf and cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf?

I added answers for all additional questions
